# Rename [google-reflections]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

The [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library doesn't appear to have any relation to Google, other than being originally hosted on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/reflections/). Should [google-reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-reflections) be renamed?

Answer (score 2):

Agreed. [reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflections) is now the primary tag, with [google-reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-reflections) merged into it and synonymized.

I've also created a stub of a wiki for the new [reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflections) tag ([google-reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-reflections) did not have any wiki at all). If you're knowledgeable about this library, I would appreciate if you could help improve the wiki.